# List.rev - This value is not a function and cannot be applied

Tags: f#

What could be a problem? Something is missing, but what exactly?

"List.rev" Gives an error - This value is not a function and cannot be applied.

I changed parameters, but it didn't work.

```
let rec b c = match c with
                | [] -> [] 
                | d :: e -> d :: (b List.rev e)
```

Output should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is here:

`(b List.rev e)`

The function `b` is a recursive function that takes a single argument - `c`. In the code above, you are passing in two arguments - the `List.rev` function and the list `e`.

You probably want this:

```ml
let rec b c =
    match c with
    | [] -> []
    | d :: e -> d :: (b (List.rev e))
```